# bash.bashrc not working for all users

Tags: bash, users, bashrc, alias, user-management

So I have 2 users on my PC when I add the line `alias abc='echo Hello'` in /etc/bash.bashrc file and log back in it only works for the first user. (the one that I changed the file) I even rebooted my PC and still didn't work.

Here's my bash.bashrc file (I know it's not necessary but just to give more info):

```
alias abc='echo Hi' # <<< Here's the line I've added



# System-wide .bashrc file for interactive bash(1) shells.

# To enable the settings / commands in this file for login shells as well,
# this file has to be sourced in /etc/profile.

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, overwrite the one in /etc/profile)
# but only if not SUDOing and have SUDO_PS1 set; then assume smart user.
if ! [ -n "${SUDO_USER}" -a -n "${SUDO_PS1}" ]; then
  PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi

# Commented out, don't overwrite xterm -T "title" -n "icontitle" by default.
# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
#case "$TERM" in
#xterm*|rxvt*)
#    PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME}: ${PWD}\007"'
#    ;;
#*)
#    ;;
#esac

# enable bash completion in interactive shells
#if ! shopt -oq posix; then
#  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
#    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
#  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
#    . /etc/bash_completion
#  fi
#fi

# sudo hint
if [ ! -e "$HOME/.sudo_as_admin_successful" ] && [ ! -e "$HOME/.hushlogin" ] ; then
    case " $(groups) " in *\ admin\ *|*\ sudo\ *)
    if [ -x /usr/bin/sudo ]; then
    cat <<-EOF
    To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>".
    See "man sudo_root" for details.
    
    EOF
    fi
    esac
fi

# if the command-not-found package is installed, use it
if [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found -o -x /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found ]; then
    function command_not_found_handle {
            # check because c-n-f could've been removed in the meantime
                if [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ]; then
           /usr/lib/command-not-found -- "$1"
                   return $?
                elif [ -x /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found ]; then
           /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found -- "$1"
                   return $?
        else
           printf "%s: command not found\n" "$1" >&2
           return 127
        fi
    }
fi
```

Also I'm running xubuntu 18.04.5 LTS.

Comment: have you tried `source etc/bash.bashrc`?

Comment: Yup, still not working.

Comment: Consider temporarily adding `[[ -f /tmp/bash.bashrc.debug ]] && echo "$USER in bash.bashrc"` just before your `alias`. Then, through `touch` and `rm` of `/tmp/bash.bashrc.debug` you can turn debug on and off.

Comment: @waltinator - Nothing happens, the file's still empty when I redo all of the things (log back in, type abc in terminal...)

Comment: Read `man bash`, the "Invocation" section. Is "my bash.bashrc" the same as `/etc/bash.bashrc`? How are you adding the line to `/etc/bash.bashrc`? Please edit your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers.

Comment: @waltinator - Yes I'm talking about /etc/bash.bashrc, also I've edited my post.

Comment: My brain's really messed up with something that's too obvious and should work, but doesn't.

Comment: How exactly are you *testing* it? what does *"not working"* mean?

Comment: Does the user which doesn't work have /bin/bash as their default shell? Look at the /etc/passwd file. (sh won't work, gets skipped in profile.

Comment: @ubfan1 - Problem solved! thanks, I didn't pay attention to the default shell and thought that It was set by default. Typing `usermod -s /bin/bash USER2` in the terminal fixed everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The /etc/bash.bashrc is sourced from /etc/profile if the user's default shell is bash.  The default shell is set in the last field of the /etc/passwd file on that user's line. If another shell is used, like /usr/bin/sh, then the /etc/profile logic says skip the sourcing of the bash.bashrc.
Change the default shell to bash with usermod:

```
usermod -s /bin/bash USER2
```